# React Native undefined function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to understand how this works in React Native. When I use this.f() it throws and error, but when I just use f(), it doesn't. I am not sure why.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

class Home extends Component {
   state = {
       myState: 'a'
   }

   updateState = () => this.setState({ myState: 'The state is updated' })
   render() {
    a = 37;
    function f() {
        return this.a;
    }
    //var f = this.f;
      return (
         <View style = {styles.container}>
            <Text onPress = {this.updateState}>
               {this.state.myState}
            </Text>
               <Text> {this.f()} </Text>
         </View>
      );
   }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingHorizontal: 30,
        paddingVertical: 30,
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
})
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` keyword in your `render()` function is a reference to the `Home` instance. `Home`'s `prototype` has no property `f` so it throws an error cause you're trying to invoke `undefined`.

The function `f()` you declared is scoped inside the `render()` function (which is definitely a bad thing to do, but that's a different topic), and `this` will be bound to the global context, or to undefined, if in strict mode. [More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).